# How to get missing branches information in coverage.py html report

Tags: code-coverage, coverage.py

Currently I am using coverage.py to get coverage report of python code. I am using --branch flag to get branch coverage in the report. In the html report header I am getting these attributes
`Module   statements  missing excluded    branches    partial coverage`
I am looking for an attribute which tells the branches_covered from which I can understand how many branches are covered or missed.
If I create a JSON report, I can see the details in the summary like

```
      "summary": {
        "covered_lines": ,
        "num_statements": ,
        "percent_covered": ,
        "percent_covered_display": ,
        "missing_lines": ,
        "excluded_lines": ,
        "num_branches": ,
        "num_partial_branches": ,
        "covered_branches": ,
        "missing_branches": 
      },
```

But I don't want to create 2 reports, I am trying to get the attribute "covered_branches" in the html report. I am not able to find solution to this yet.

Comment: Yes, the two reports have slightly different subsets of the data.  Can you say more about why you don't want to make 2 reports? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: because we were using a dashboard kind of report with html report and adding json report is not user friendly